# Best modelling approach with binary outcome and some non-linear relationships, including some "definite 0" regions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, nonlinear-regression

I have 5 predictors and a binary outcome.

One of the predictors (X4) is already very informative of the outcome. Basically, for all X4 values that are 0:100, all outcomes are 0. For values 100:150, the vast majority of outcomes are "1" except for a few near the edges of that range. For values 200 on, all outcomes are 0 again.

So really, a decent model already could be "0 for all values except for if X4 is 100:150... for that range, use a logistic regression". Would that have to be a GAM model? Or could random forest be good? Or a neural network?

So far I simply used a dummy variable that is 0 unless X4 is in the range 100:150, and include interaction effects between that variable and all the others. This gives me near perfect prediction on the test set, but I'm curious if there's a non-manual way to do this (I wanted the machine to do the learning, not me!)

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a scatterplot of outcome vs X4? That will give a better idea of what models might be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If you managed to get a low test error with your simple model then you will probably get a good fitting as well with other models.

However, unlike other models, a random forest classifier (RFC) offers a really nice way to test whether or not the model has learned your intuition/information about the importance of features. This can be done through the feature importance property of RFC.  See [this](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/trees_and_forests/feature_importance/) as an example.